# Vue JS custom plugin props not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm building a Vue JS custom plugin which has some options that can be passed as props. I'm building the plugin using the `vue-cli-plugin-p11n` package which works perfectly!

However, including and initialising the plugin in a generic website, such as a HTML webpage doesn't seem to update the value of the props that I pass.

My props are as follows:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    isModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true
    }
  }
}
```

I then include my plugin in my HTML webpage as:

```html
<div id="vue-offers--plugin">
  <vue-les-offers
    :isModal="false"
    class="test"
    >
  </vue-les-offers>
</div>
```

I then initialise the plugin:

```html
<script>
  // Initialise dependencies
  Vue.use(VueResource)

  new Vue({
  }).$mount('#vue-offers--plugin')
</script>
```

However, passing `isModal` doesn't update the value? Is it being read correctly?

Comment: Do you have some error messages in console?

Comment: I have a single error message relating to the value of one of my prop options, however, I should be able to customise the option by passing a value through it, which isn't working.

Comment: It's just a 404 error, not an error related to code.

Comment: Can you show that `a single error message relating to the value of one of my prop options`?

Comment: I figured it out, you can't use a prop as camelcase, it has to be `is-modal`